# How to test if a model has an attribute with custom models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model like this:

```
class ForgotPasswordForm
    include ActiveModel::Model
    include ActiveModel::Validations

    attr_accessor :email

    validates_presence_of :email

end
```

I want to create a module, and I want to test if the model using the module has a certain attribute.

I will then include that module into the above ForgotPasswordForm.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
`ForgotPasswordForm.attribute_names`

Comment: I want to test this from inside of my module.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.